# Pre-images under the multiplication map $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ of open intervals are open

Tags: general-topology, functions

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x,y) = xy$. Find the pre-image $f^{-1}((a,b))$ of an open interval $(a, b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and show that this pre-image is open in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

I can't seem to conceptualize this, and I didn't know what the graph looked like during the exam either. If we have an interval $(a, b)$, then the pre-image will be a bunch of ordered pairs/coordinates on the $\mathbb{R^2}$ plane. So the pre-image of an interval like $(2, 3)$ would have some coordinates whose first and second components multiply to some number in the interval $(2, 3)$. How can I generalize this, and also show this generalization is an open set in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider $(-1,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$ then you can easily verify that the preimage of $(-1,1)$ under $f$ is the region between the graph of the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: I am trying to find the pre-image of $(-1, 1)$ under $f$. So I have to find all the numbers that you can multiply together that gives us any number between $-1$ and $1$. This seems like a lot of possibilities to write down by hand. Is there an easier method?

Comment: The possibilities for $1$ or $-1$ are pretty easy, right?  When $y=\frac{1}{x}$ or $y=-\frac{1}{x}$.... so then after a moment's thought you will realize that the points that output values between $-1$ and $1$ will be forced to lie between the curves $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and $y=-\frac{1}{x}$ since these are bounds on the values.

Answer (score 1):

First, addressing your visualization question. You might first ask yourself: what is the set of points satisfying $f(x,y)=c$, where $c$ is some constant, say 1. Well, $f(x,y)=1$ is satisfied by the poitns on the arcs $y=1/x$. $f(x,y)=2$ is satisfied by the points on the arcs $y=2/x$. Draw these arcs on the same diagram. Now, what is the set of points satisfying $f(x,y)=c$ where $1<c<2$? It is the "open band of arcs" between what you currently have drawn on your diagram. Intuitively, it looks open (read: intuitively).

Now, we prove rigorously that $f$ is continuous, hence solving the problem. That multiplication is continuous as a map from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ can be found easily on the web. Here's a proof.

**Proof:** Fix the point $(x_0,y_0)$ and $0<\epsilon<1$. Take $\delta = \min(\frac{\epsilon} {|x_0|+|y_0|+1},1)$. Then for $(x,y)$ within $\delta$ distance from $(x_0,y_0)$, we have (by definition of norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as max of coordinate difference) that $|x-x_0|,|y-y_0|<\delta$ and therefore:

$$|xy-x_0y_0|\\
=|(x-x_0)(y-y_0)+x_0(y-y_0)+y_0(x-x_0)|\\
\le|x-x_0||y-y_0|+|x_0||y-y_0|+|y_0||x-x_0|\\
<\delta^2 + \delta |x_0| + \delta |y_0|\\
\le \delta(1+|x_0|+|y_0|)\\
\le\epsilon$$